# Eloquent: How to define a one-to-one relationship on the same model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Say I have a Tennis players model, and each player has a mate they're tied to for doubles games. How would I define that relationship in Eloquent? I'm used to the usual scenario in the docs (and have seen the same in many codebases) where the one-to-one relationship points to an entry in another table which makes it straight-forward where to put `hasOne()` and `belongsTo()`.

A player can only have one mate plus no two players share the same mate, and their relationship is determined by the value in a `mate_id` field. So ideally I'd want to do `$player->mate` to get the mate.

So what goes in the `mate()` method that I'll add on the Player model, to satisfy the requirement of a `hasOne()` and `belongsTo()` as [shown in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-to-one as I want it works when I define only the `belongsTo()`, it won't work if I use `hasOne()` as in the other answers.

```
public function mate()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Player', 'mate_id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't hasOne relation work here?

Try this in your model

```
public function mate()
{
        return $this->hasOne('Player', 'mate_id');
}
```

I don't think we would need the reverse relationship, as doing $player->mate() on any one player will give the other.

Comment: Where then would we define the `belongsTo()`?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer I think we won't need a revese relationship i.e belongsTo wouldn't be required. Would it apply?

Comment: Let me try and see. Didn't work yesterday but it could have been for some other reason because I was tweaking the migrations at the point. Will let you know soon. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work. It wanted `belongsTo()`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make new table, which might be called "mate".

mate

id

player_id (unique, not null)

player_id (unique, not null)

Then you pair them from Players table with belongsToMany().

Unique constraint says that a Player cant be in more than 1 pair.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess that's the last option on the table (no pun). Just trying a few things with your approach, will let you know. Thanks Siim.